# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,409.32 ' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, numeric, varchar

I have a `USRDEF05 varchar(30)` column in `SOP10106` table declared as column that contains all numbers, when I try to execute below query I am getting conversion error.

```
Select 
    DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
    CASE 
       when USERDEF.USRDEF05 <> ' ' THEN USERDEF.USRDEF05 
       ELSE 0 
    END as Winsys
FROM 
    SOP10100 DETAIL
Right JOIN 
    SOP10106 USERDEF ON USERDEF.soptype = DETAIL.soptype 
WHERE 
    BACHNUMB ='WINSYS112012'
```

Can anybody give me an idea how to solve this error?

Comment: And how `1,409.32` is supposed to be converted to int?

Comment: 1,409.32 is not a int. so how could sql convert it into int??

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
CASE when ISNUMERIC(USERDEF.USRDEF05) <> 0 THEN 
CAST(CAST(USERDEF.USRDEF05 as DECIMAL) as int) ELSE 0 END as Winsys
```

> NOTE:- This will round off the decimal value to nearest integer.

eg:- if your value is 1409.32, the resulting int value is 1409

if your value is 1409.64, then resulting int value is 1410

Comment: Thanks sachin for your reply,value of USRDEF05 should not be rounded. using aboue quary i am getting this error ... Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @NeeruBindela - If USRDEF05 is not to be rounded, then can you explain how to convert 1409.32 into integer value? Also did you try the `CAST` which i have suggested in your query?

Comment: Yes i tried, this is giving message like : Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: @NeeruBindela - Can you put your updated query?, I have a test query which is working for me. Or can you check if any data in your column is actually not an integer? Only in that case, this error is expected

Answer (score 0):

Because your database schema is incorrect (numbers are not supposed to stored as text), then next incorrect statement should work also:

```
Select 
    DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
    CASE 
       when USERDEF.USRDEF05 <> ' ' THEN USERDEF.USRDEF05 
       ELSE '0' 
    END as Winsys
```

Answer (score 0):

I am really don't what you  try to receive because `USRDEF05` is string but seems you want that `Winsys` will be numeric.

Here are a couple ways:

**`Winsys` is string**

```
Select 
DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
CASE 
   when USERDEF.USRDEF05 <> ' ' THEN USERDEF.USRDEF05 
   ELSE '0' 
END as Winsys
```

**`Winsys` is numeric**

```
Select 
DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
CASE 
   when USERDEF.USRDEF05 <> ' ' THEN CONVERT(MONEY, USERDEF.USRDEF05, 1)
   ELSE 0 
END as Winsys
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not in this value 1,409.32
Try to run this query using [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) function:

```
Select 
    DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
    CASE 
       when isnumeric(USERDEF.USRDEF05) = 1 
            THEN cast(USERDEF.USRDEF05 as decimal(12,2))
       ELSE 0 
    END as Winsys
FROM 
    SOP10100 DETAIL
Right JOIN 
    SOP10106 USERDEF ON USERDEF.soptype = DETAIL.soptype 
WHERE 
    BACHNUMB ='WINSYS112012'
```

And also check where is an error:

```
select USRDEF05 from USERDEF 
where isnumeric(USERDEF.USRDEF05) = 0 
and USERDEF.USRDEF05 <> ' '
```